# What are the EASA myopia limits for civil flight certification, class 2?

Tags: easa-regulations, medical, pilot-certification

I want to start procedures to get a flight medical certification (class 2).

I am not sure about myopia (short-sight) limits.

In some resources I read that there are no limits, and you can wear glasses. In other resources I read that they are very strict.

Could someone who knows, please clarify this confusing topic?
Thank you very much.

EDIT:
This is about Greece

Comment: @Bianfable Done! I edited the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EASA [class two requirements](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Easy_Access_Rules_for_Medical_Requirements.pdf) are (p.99):

> (2) For a class 2 medical certificate:
>
> (i) Distant visual acuity, with or without correction, shall be 6/12
> (0,5) or better in each eye separately and visual acuity with both
> eyes shall be 6/9 (0,7) or better.
>
> (ii) Notwithstanding point (b)(2)(i), applicants with substandard
> vision in one eye or monocularity may be assessed as fit, in
> consultation with the medical assessor of the licensing authority and
> subject to a satisfactory ophthalmological evaluation.

Note that it says "with or without correction", which means that you can wear glasses or contact lenses.

Comment: Thank you, but i don't understand what is the point to a myopia limit if you can wear glasses. You can have 10 myopia, and with glasses, you drop to zero. So what exactly does this mean?

Comment: @user1584421 I don’t know about EASA, but the US has more or less the same wording. Here it has two effects: if someone can’t meet the myopia limit even with glasses then they can’t get that class of medical. Second, if they need glasses to meet the limit then there will be a restriction on their medical that requires them to wear glasses while flying.

Answer (score 2):

EASA Part-MED regulations are non black and white. There is some margin up to the discretion of the AME and Optometrist. If you are outside of the limits, you may be asked to undergo further examinations.

Corrections (Spectacles/contact lenses) are allowed and mandatory depending on your non-corrected visual acuity.